# Using a timer for a game in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift3, timer

I am using a timer for a game in Swift. It controls the speed of asteroids falling. I would like the speed of the asteroids to fall more quickly after the score has reached a certain level, however, the speed remains the same. I suspect this is because the repeat value is set to true and it is stuck in a loop of sorts.

```
    if score <= 10 {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: 0.8, secondNumber: 5)), target: self, selector: #selector (GameScene.leftTraffic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: 0.8, secondNumber: 5)), target: self, selector: #selector (GameScene.rightTraffic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }else {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: 0.8, secondNumber: 1)), target: self, selector: #selector (GameScene.leftTraffic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: 0.8, secondNumber: 1)), target: self, selector: #selector (GameScene.rightTraffic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Edit:

I have changed the code based on a recommendation but the asteroids still fall after the timer has been invalidated.

```
        let lowSpeedLeft =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: 0.8, secondNumber: 2)), target: self, selector: #selector (GameScene.leftTraffic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    let lowSpeedRight = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(Helper().randomBetweenTwoNumbers(firstNumber: 0.8, secondNumber: 2)), target: self, selector: #selector (GameScene.rightTraffic), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    if !stopEverything{
        if score <= 10{
            lowSpeedLeft.fire()
            lowSpeedRight.fire()
        }else if score > 10{
            lowSpeedLeft.invalidate()
            lowSpeedRight.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you fire timers, you should keep their instance. When the score changes, you should `timer.invalidate()` and create the new timer and start it off.

Comment: I have done what you say but the asteroids still continue to fall after the timer has been invalidated. Please check the edit section of my original post to see how I coded it. I am very new to coding and greatly appreciate the help!